# Shopify REST API: Unable to add a new product variant with new option type getting error "Option values provided for 1 unknown option(s)"

Tags: rest, shopify, shopify-api

when creating a product in Shopify via the REST API, adds a default option and variant like below

```
"options": [
        {
            "id": 9651869188247,
            "product_id": 7644173172887,
            "name": "Title",
            "position": 1,
            "values": [
                "Default Title"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Variants:

```
{
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": 42211487744151,
            "product_id": 7644173172887,
            "title": "Default Title",
            "price": "1.00",
            "sku": "",
            "position": 1,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "Default Title",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2022-06-17T17:18:24+05:30",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-17T17:18:24+05:30",
            "taxable": true,
            "barcode": null,
            "grams": 0,
            "image_id": null,
            "weight": 0.0,
            "weight_unit": "kg",
            "inventory_item_id": 44310083534999,
            "inventory_quantity": 0,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 0,
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42211487744151"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the existing Option and Variants of a product to show "Color" & "Size" as options and variants of them. For that I tried the Shopify Rest API but that still is raising the below error

request model:

```
{
  "variant": {
      "product_id": 7644173172887,
      "option1": "red",
      "option2": "small",
      "price": "1.0",
      "title": "S"
    }
}
```

response :

```
{
    "errors": {
        "base": [
            "Option values provided for 1 unknown option(s)"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What endpoint are you using for the request?

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifing what endpoint you're using but I can see that you're specifing the Product Id and that should not be the case. If you need to add a new variant this is the request you should do

`POST https://yourstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/products/7644173172887/variants.json`

```
{"variant":{"option1":"Red", "option2" :"Small", "title": "Red", "price":"1.00"}}
```

You will also need to update the current "Default Title" variant (I suggest, if possible to create the product with a valid variant).

`PUT https://yourstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/variants/42211487744151.json`

```
{"variant":{"id":42211487744151,"option1":"Red","option2" : "S", "price":"99.00", "title" : "Red"}}
```